# Load Subform with Record if it exist after Main Form text box Selection

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good day all

I have a Main Form/Subform setup for Data Entry. On the Main form, I have the PID field setup for no duplicates (this is locked and is filled with an expression via VBA `Me.PID = DMax("PID", "PurchaseDetail") + 1` to add a custom ID), a combo box (VID) to select the Vendor and a Date textbox (PDATE). On the subform, I enter the details of the Purchase ie Product, Quantity, Cost etc. The form and subform are linked by PDate and VID. After the date is entered I have an event to look for records with the same VID and Date before continuing with Data Entry.

```
Private Sub PDATE_AfterUpdate()

Dim RecordChk As Long
Dim Answer As Integer
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
RecordChk = CDbl(Me.PDATE) & Me.VID
    
If DCount("*", "PurchaseDetail", "Key = " & RecordChk & "") <> 0 Then 
    Answer = MsgBox("Record already exist. View Bill?", vbYesNo, "Duplicate Record!!")
        If Answer = vbYes Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "INVCOST", acNormal, , "[qryInvCost].[KEY]= " & RecordChk & ""
        Else
            Me.subfrmPurchases.Form!cboProductName.SetFocus
        End If
End If
End Sub
```

Instead of opening a separate form (INVCOST) to the existing record is there any way to load the existing record details into the subform?

Comment: Is main form bound to data? I would not use compound key linking. Edit question to show sample data schema and relationship these forms are based on. Usual approach is to filter main form and its related subform records synchronize.

Comment: Yes the main form is bound to the subform. With the Data Entry property off I am able to cycle records but with it on I want to be able to load the record if it exist.

Comment: You mean forms are linked by Master/Child Links properties of subform container? If DataEntry property is set to Yes then it cannot display the new record added by code. Can only display records added by manual data entry in a single session. That's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

As June7 has commented, forms should be linked via Master/Child links properties. If they are, there should be no need to search for existing records, if some exist, if you filter the main form as June7 suggested. They should automatically appear. Do you also want the ability to add new records in the subform or are you just editing existing subform data? If you are looking to have both existing subform records that are editable, and the ability to enter a new record in the subform manually, set the subform to AllowAdditions and AllowEdits. It will not need to be set to DataEntry.

Comment: Ok so I set the Data Entry property to "No" and inserted this line  `Me.Filter = "[VID]='" & Me.VID & "' and [PurDate] = #" & Me.PDATE & "# " Me.FilterOn = True` Now the problem is to remove the CustomID from the PID field. It is not allowing the filter because the PID field is filled before the VID gets focus.